# The navigation buttons for pages on a forked and edited GitHub website no longer work

Tags: github, github-pages

The navigation buttons on a GitHub hosted website don't take me to the page, and I am unsure how to fix it.

I am very new to GitHub, but am looking to make a webpage for the lab I work in. I found an existing lab webpage (https://github.com/KordingLab/KordingLab.github.io) that allows you to make forks and edit it for your own purposes, which was a great base. I've since changed the repository name but now when I load the page, the navigation buttons don't go to the pages automatically. My website name is `myusername.github.io/repository`, while when I click the "people" page navigation button, it tries to go to `myusername.github.io/people` which doesn't exist.

I can manually type in `myusername.github.io/repository/people`, and the page will come out. Obviously along the way of changing in my teams name while editing, I have messed this up a bit.

The outlay of the original website is `kordinglab.com/people`, which doesn't include the repository name which is why I think it won't navigate to include the repository. I've had a look through the code, but as I am a bit inexperienced, I can't find how to change it, or where it is controlled.

How can I fix it so the nav buttons actually go to the pages?

https://github.com/KordingLab/KordingLab.github.io provides all the code used in the original and working version. I would be more specific if I knew which file I was looking for, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally we require code to be included in your question. Having to go off-site to read code significantly limits how helpful questions can be to future readers.

However, in this case I think we can give a helpful answer without leaning too hard on that code. It's really an answer about *how to find* what you're looking for.

In this case, you want o find something that defines a link to `people`, or something like it. You can use GitHub's search to [search for that value](https://github.com/KordingLab/KordingLab.github.io/search?q=people&unscoped_q=people). Alternatively, you can use your text editor's search.

Either way, among your results you should see a file called [`_config.yml`](https://github.com/KordingLab/KordingLab.github.io/blob/master/_config.yml) that contains, among other things, a section that looks like this:

```
# Navigation
nav:
  - name:           "home"
    href:           "/"
  - name:           "about"
    href:           "/about"
  - name:           "publications"
    href:           "/publication"
  - name:           "people"
    href:           "/people"
  - name:           "blog"
    href:           "/blog"
```

The `href`s here likely control the target of the named links in your site navigation. Update them to prefix `/repository`, redeploy, and you should be all set.